# servicestack.text deserializing array to object

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

I have a REST-Service build with ServicStack and in one call the user can send different types of values. So I made the property in C# of type object.

The JSON that is sent looks like this:

```
{"name":"ffff","params":[{"pId":1,"value":[624,625]},{"pId":2,"value":"xxx"}]}
```

The part "value":[624,625] results in a string object filled with "[624,625]". I was hoping to get an int-array or at least a string array, but it is plain string.
I set JsConfig.TryToParsePrimitiveTypeValues = true, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

I tried the latest sources from github.

Can this be done with any combination of switches or must I parse this myself?

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is some testcode:

```
[TestMethod]
public void JsonTest()
{
    string json = "{\"name\":\"ffff\",\"params\":[{\"pId\":1,\"value\":[624,625]},{\"pId\":2,\"value\":\"xxx\"}]}";

    var x = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<xy>(json);
    Assert.AreEqual(x.Params[0].Value.GetType(), typeof(int[]));
}

public class xy
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Param> Params { get; set; }
}

public class Param
{
    public int PId { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What code are you using to deserialise this JSON?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the type of "Value" to int array as follows, then ServiceStack will serialize to array of int.

```
    public class Param
    {
        public int PId { get; set; }

        public int[] Value { get; set; }
    }
```

The following unit test passes:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void JsonTest()
    {
        string json = "{\"name\":\"ffff\",\"params\":[{\"pId\":1,\"value\":[624,625]},{\"pId\":2,\"value\":\"xxx\"}]}";

        var x = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<xy>(json);
        Assert.AreEqual(x.Params[0].Value.GetType(), typeof(int[]));
        // Show that we have some integers
        Assert.IsTrue(x.Params[0].Value.Count()>0);
    }
```

If you cannot change the type of Value for any reason, then you can use ServiceStack.Text to serialize the string into an array as needed.